# Can any one suggest me on how to update the below code?

Tags: apex

I want to remove `else if` and put `else if` condition in 3rd `if or if` using `&&` or `||` possible please suggest can we do and if yes than how.

```java
for(AccountContactRelation con : accoutConRelatedList){
    if(!acrRolesList.isEmpty()){
        for(String roleValue:acrRolesList){
            if(acrRoleMap.containsKey(con.contact.contact_id__c+'-'+con.Account.customer_id__c) 
                && acrRoleMap.get(con.contact.contact_id__c+'-'+con.Account.customer_id__c).contains(roleValue)){
                    
                    businessAcctMap.put(con.contact.contact_id__c+'-'+con.Account.customer_id__c+'-'+roleValue,con.Account.Id);
                    
                    if(jobRolegreatrthan25.contains(roleValue) && (roleValue.equals('B5') && con.Ownership_Perc_B5__c >= 25) ||
                        (!jobRolegreatrthan25.contains(roleValue) && !skipConRoleSet.contains(roleValue))
                           || (roleValue.equals('F6') && con.Ownership_Perc_F6__c >= 25) 
                           || (roleValue.equals('R3') && con.Ownership_Perc_R3__c >= 25) 
                           || (roleValue.equals('F7') && con.Ownership_Perc_F7__c >= 25)){
                            
                        accountContactJobRoleMap.put(con.contact.contact_id__c+'-'+con.Account.customer_id__c+'-'+roleValue,roleValue);
                        indAccttoBusActMap.put(con.contact.contact_id__c+'-'+con.Account.customer_id__c+'-'+roleValue,indAccountIdMap.get(con.contact.contact_id__c)); 
                    }
                    else if(!jobRolegreatrthan25.contains(roleValue) && !skipConRoleSet.contains(roleValue)){
                        accountContactJobRoleMap.put(con.contact.contact_id__c+'-'+con.Account.customer_id__c+'-'+roleValue,roleValue); 
                        indAccttoBusActMap.put(con.contact.contact_id__c+'-'+con.Account.customer_id__c+'-'+roleValue,indAccountIdMap.get(con.contact.contact_id__c)); 
                    }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to refactor your code a bit and reduce nesting depth:

```
for (AccountContactRelation con : accoutConRelatedList) {
    String complexKey = con.contact.contact_id__c + '-' + con.Account.customer_id__c;
    for (String roleValue : acrRolesList) {
        if (!acrRoleMap.containsKey(complexKey) || !acrRoleMap.get(complexKey).contains(roleValue)) continue;

        businessAcctMap.put(con.contact.contact_id__c + '-' + con.Account.customer_id__c + '-' + roleValue, con.Account.Id);

        if (jobRolegreatrthan25.contains(roleValue) && (roleValue.equals('B5') && con.Ownership_Perc_B5__c >= 25) ||
            (!jobRolegreatrthan25.contains(roleValue) && !skipConRoleSet.contains(roleValue))
            || (roleValue.equals('F6') && con.Ownership_Perc_F6__c >= 25)
            || (roleValue.equals('R3') && con.Ownership_Perc_R3__c >= 25)
            || (roleValue.equals('F7') && con.Ownership_Perc_F7__c >= 25)) {

            accountContactJobRoleMap.put(con.contact.contact_id__c + '-' + con.Account.customer_id__c + '-' + roleValue, roleValue);
            indAccttoBusActMap.put(con.contact.contact_id__c + '-' + con.Account.customer_id__c + '-' + roleValue, indAccountIdMap.get(con.contact.contact_id__c));
        } else if (!jobRolegreatrthan25.contains(roleValue) && !skipConRoleSet.contains(roleValue)) {
            accountContactJobRoleMap.put(con.contact.contact_id__c + '-' + con.Account.customer_id__c + '-' + roleValue, roleValue);
            indAccttoBusActMap.put(con.contact.contact_id__c + '-' + con.Account.customer_id__c + '-' + roleValue, indAccountIdMap.get(con.contact.contact_id__c));
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding your question, you can move your else if

```
if ((jobRolegreatrthan25.contains(roleValue) 
            && ((roleValue.equals('B5') && con.Ownership_Perc_B5__c >= 25) 
            || (roleValue.equals('F6') && con.Ownership_Perc_F6__c >= 25)
            || (roleValue.equals('R3') && con.Ownership_Perc_R3__c >= 25)
            || (roleValue.equals('F7') && con.Ownership_Perc_F7__c >= 25))) 
                || (!jobRolegreatrthan25.contains(roleValue) && !skipConRoleSet.contains(roleValue)))
```

Comment: refactoring code my set and map is initialized like 
Set<String> acrRolesList = new Set<String>();---> acrRolesList.addAll(acr.roles.split(';'));
Map<String,Set<String>> acrRoleMap = new Map<String,Set<String>>();---> acrRoleMap.put(key,new Set<String>(acr.Roles.split(';')));  
so you have removed my 2nd line  if(!acrRolesList.isEmpty()) and put single 
condition if does it work ??? if i can remove my 2nd line if condition with this if (!acrRoleMap.containsKey(complexKey) || !acrRoleMap.get(complexKey)

Comment: @user121342 we don't need to check if acrRolesList is not empty as we going to use it in foreach